# How can I insert the same word from a list that was randomly chosen earlier in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, random

I am creating a random sentence generator for a course assignment. I have everything pretty much figured out but there is a spot in the sentence template we have to use where I need to first randomly choose a word, then repeat that randomly chosen word again in the string. The problem occurs after random.choice(place) when I need to immediately use whatever word was chosen again. How can I grab that same word that was randomly chosen and use it again?

```
import random

verb = ["dancing", "driving", "running"]
place = ["rain", "forest", "city"]
adjective = ["heavy", "long", "hard"]

count = 1

while count > 0:

    generate = int(input('Press 1 to generate a new sentence or 2 to exit.\n'))

    if generate == 1:
        print('I like to go',random.choice(verb),'in the',random.choice(place),',but',place,'should not be too',random.choice(adjective),'.')
        count = 1

    else:
        print('Ok, Goodbye!')
        count = 0
```

Comment: look up python string formatting

Comment: You store it in a variable, and use the variable as many times as you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to use a variable to store your `random.choice(place)` before printing it, so you avoid randomizing it twice.

```
if generate == 1:
        myplace = random.choice(place)
        print('I like to go',random.choice(verb),'in the',myplace,',but',myplace,'should not be too',random.choice(adjective),'.')
        count = 1
```

Just for fun, you could also use `format` to substitute names in a string without needing a variable.

```
if generate == 1:
        print('I like to go {verb} in the {place}, but {place} should not be too {adjective}.'.format(verb=random.choice(verb),place=random.choice(place),adjective=random.choice(adjective))
        count = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great now. Still new to this and learning. I think it's amazing there are so many different ways to do everything.